# Change default location log file generated by logger in python

Tags: python, logging, filehandler

I am using logger in my python source code, and want  to create logs on specific location but **python logging** module creates the log files at the default place i.e. from where it is executed.

Is there is any way to change this default location?

below is my configuration

```
  import logging
  logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
  logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s', datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', filename='testGene.log, filemode='w')
```

Comment: You should do your `basicConfig` call first, I think.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s', datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', filename='path/to/your/directory/testGene.log', filemode='w')
```

Or

```
import logging
import os
if not os.path.exists("Logs"):
    os.makedirs("Logs")
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s', datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', filename='Logs/testGene.log', filemode='w')
```

Comment: This will not work, when you run the python source code it will try to add below two location which will end up with error "No such file or directory"
1: path location of log file
2: location from where script is executed

Comment: @AmanJaiswal It will run if your platform is Linux. And by default, it will add path for the current working directory.

Comment: Please try to run given solution from multiple places and you will end up creating multiple folder, this will never going to target only one destination folder

Answer (score 2):

Create a module name `log_to_text_file.py` with the following code:

```py
import logging, logging.handlers
def get_logger(module_name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(module_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s : %(name)s : %(message)s')
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('//loglocation/application.log')
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    if (logger.hasHandlers()):
        logger.handlers.clear()
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    return logger
```

Import the module in the beginning of other modules and call the function like this:

```py
log = get_logger(__name__)                                                    
log.info(f"this is info logging)
log.exception("This is exception logging")
```

Comment: yeah, root logger 's handlers is a empty list at beginning, if you have config it to output to a file and after a while you want to change the output destination to another file, you should call "logger.handlers.clear()" at first, otherwise "logging.basicConfig" may not take effect.

Answer (score 1):

When initializing logger specify location where you want your logs to be saved.

```
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.config',
                      defaults={'yourlogfile': '/path/to/log/file'})
```

Comment: This will not work, when you run the python source code it will try to add below two location which will end up with error "No such file or directory"
1: path location of log file
2: location from where script is executed

Answer (score 1):

```
import logging as log
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

if not os.path.exists(dir_path+"/Logs"):
    os.makedirs(dir_path+"/Logs")

log.basicConfig(level=log.DEBUG,
                format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s',
                datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
                handlers=[log.FileHandler(dir_path+'/Logs/file_logs.log'),
                          log.StreamHandler()]
                )
```