# Setting log file and report HTML file locations

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging

Below references to questions that have helped me get this far (there's been many more but I didn't save the links unfortunately):

- [Change default location log file generated by logger in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50981906/change-default-location-log-file-generated-by-logger-in-python)
- [Setting dynamic folder and report name in pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60571675/setting-dynamic-folder-and-report-name-in-pytest)

I want to specify the file name and location of both the `.log` file and the `.html` report file.

Below is my latest attempt at it.

Function to "create" the `fileHandler` logger:

```
def define_file_logger(log_level, formatter, file_location):
    # create directory
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(file_location), exist_ok=True)

    # create file handler for logging to file
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename=Path(file_location) / 'log.log')
    file_handler.setLevel(log_level)

    # apply formatter to file handler logger
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    # request logger
    final_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    # prevent double logs in console
    if final_logger.hasHandlers():
        final_logger.handlers.clear()

    final_logger.propagate = False

    # add handler
    final_logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    # return
    return final_logger
```

My `config.py` file (in the `root` directory):

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def pytest_load_initial_conftests(args, early_config, parser):
    os.environ['reports_dir'] = str(Path('Reports', f'{datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y")}', f'{datetime.now().strftime("%H.%M")}'))
```

My `conftest.py` file (in the `root` directory):

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def pytest_configure(config):
    # set custom options only if none are provided from command line
    if not config.option.htmlpath:
        # set path and file name
        config.option.htmlpath = Path(os.environ['reports_dir']) / 'report.html'
        config.option.self_contained_html = True
```

When I run this, I get the error:

> No such file or directory

I can get it so that the `log` file is generated in the `root` directory and the `html` report in the `reports` directory if I make this change to the `define_file_logger` function:

***Before:***

```
# create file handler for logging to file
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename=Path(file_location) / 'log.log')
```

***After:***

```
# create file handler for logging to file
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='log.log')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came back to this and actually managed to figure it out..

This section:

```
# create directory
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(file_location), exist_ok=True)
```

Wasn't creating my desired directory.

The directory should have been like this:

```
├── Reports
│   └── 08.03.2022
│       ├── 08.35
│       │   └── report.html
│       └── 08.44
│           ├── Execution_Log.log
│           └── report.html
```

Which is essentially:

> Reports > Date > Time > file

BUT it was getting caught up on the folder creation for the TIME folder (for whatever reason).

So now, I have this:

`config.py` in `src` directory:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def pytest_load_initial_conftests(args, early_config, parser):
    # set directories
    os.environ['current_dir'] = str(Path(__file__))
    os.environ['project_dir'] = str(str([p for p in Path(os.environ['current_dir']).parents if p.parts[-1] == 'src'][0]))
    os.environ['reports_dir'] = str(Path('Reports', f'{datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y")}', f'{datetime.now().strftime("%H.%M")}'))
```

`conftest.py` in `src` directory:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def pytest_configure(config):
    # set path and file name
    config.option.htmlpath = Path(os.environ['reports_dir'], 'report.html')
    config.option.self_contained_html = True
```

`custom_logger.py` (doesn't have to be in `src` directory):

```
def define_file_logger(log_level: str, formatter: logging.Formatter, file_location: str = None) -> logging.FileHandler:
    # create directory
    os.makedirs(file_location, exist_ok=True)

    # create file handler for logging to file
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename=Path(os.environ['reports_dir'], 'Execution_Log.log'))
    file_handler.setLevel(LOG_MAP[log_level])

    # apply formatter to file handler logger
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    # return logger
    return file_handler
```

I believe this is what the cause of my issue was:

```
# create directory
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(file_location), exist_ok=True)
```

Should not have included `os.path.dirname`, like this:

```
# create directory
os.makedirs(file_location, exist_ok=True)
```

I also changed this (`Path(file_location) / 'log.log'`):

```
# create file handler for logging to file
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename=Path(file_location) / 'log.log')
```

To this:

```
# create file handler for logging to file
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename=Path(file_location, 'log.log'))
```